# How to find MAX value from two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, max

I am learning SQL and experimenting with SQL Server. I have two tables.

Table1

```
+------+--------+--------+
|  IDK |  CODE  |  NAME  | 
+------+--------+--------+
|  1   |   742  |   PEN  |
|  2   |   853  |   PEN  |
|  3   |   724  | PAPPER |
|  4   |   544  |   PEN  |
|  5   |   451  | PRINTER|
+------+--------+--------+
```

Table2

```
+------+--------+
|  IDK |   QTY  | 
+------+--------+
|  1   |   154  | 
|  2   |   85   |  
|  3   |   74   |
|  4   |   44   |
|  5   |   51   |
+------+--------+
```

I want to find the `CODE` with the highest `QTY` which has the name PEN.
I have a variable `myname = "PEN"`

I have tried:

```
SELECT Table1.CODE
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.IDK = Table2.IDK
WHERE Table2.QTY = (SELECT MAX(Table2.QTY) FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.NAME = :myname)
```

What should I write in order to return `742`?

Comment: can you also add details of `MTRDATA` table, so others can understand what exactly you are trying ?

Comment: You are right I fixed it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common table expressions can really be useful for this question.  The "core" table that you really want to be querying is actually tables 1 and 2 joined together.  By placing this join into a CTE, we can easily reuse it to get the answer you seek.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT t1.IDK,
       t1.CODE,
       t1.NAME,
       t2.QTY
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.IDK = t2.IDK
);

SELECT t.CODE
FROM cte t
WHERE t.NAME = 'PEN' AND
      t.QTY = (SELECT MAX(QTY) FROM cte WHERE NAME = 'PEN')
```

Comment: That worked great! But do you really need the following line of code: `t.NAME = 'PEN' AND`?

Comment: @John Yes, I believe you need this.  The first part of the `WHERE` clause restricts to records which are pens, and the second part chooses the pen record with the highest quantity of all pens.

Comment: Ok I agree but don't you include it below?
 t.QTY = (SELECT MAX(QTY) FROM cte `WHERE NAME = 'PEN'`)

Comment: This is just the subquery which identifies the max value.  You still need to restrict the table in the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max and then perorm a `JOIN` like

```
select t1.CODE
from table1 t1
join (select top 1 IDK from table2 order by QTY desc) xxx
on t1.IDK = xxx.IDK
where t1.Name = 'PEN';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track and you should tweak your simple query before going to something fancy - Occam's Razor. You just need to *order the query* and then *limit the number of results of the query*. This is an area where the major SQL distributions are inconsistent and I'm not sure if it's due to lack of design in the SQL spec or rogue language definition by the manufacturers.

In Oracle and Postgres you'll need OFFSET and LIMIT, in MySQL you'll need just LIMIT, and with IBM DB2 you'll use FETCH FIRST, all positioned near the end of the query. **When using T-SQL (for MS SQL Server), you'll be using TOP in the SELECT.**

```
DECLARE @myname VARCHAR(32) = 'PEN'

SELECT TOP 1 
    t1.CODE
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.IDK = t2.IDK
WHERE t1.NAME = @myname
ORDER BY t2.QTY
```

At your stage of database programming, I'd caution you against using in memory tables without understanding the consequences. They are a fantastic tool for OLAP and other analysis but can have unintended performance consequences in environments where resources are subject to competition or are under constraint.

Also, avoid nesting queries when unnecessary for readability, maintainability, and performance. Every level of nesting adds a dimension to the volume of data processed and query time has a roughly 1:1 ratio with volume of data. In this scenario nesting and JOINing will have the same effect on data size but nesting will preclude some of the databases ability to optimize . Both of these strategies are excellent under the right purposes, but as someone learning, make sure you understand both of them before becoming reliant on them.